# Finding rows in R dataframe where a column value follows a sequence

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below which is an output of a classifier.

```
col1, class
 123, 2
 122, 5
 124, 7
 125, 9
 126, 15
 127, 2
 128, 19
 129, 5
 130, 7
 179, 9
 180, 3
```

I want to find the rows that has a certain pattern of class, like all rows  whose classes are in seq `5,7,9`.

The solution I came up with is pasting class columns by shifting one row and comparing columns as below

```
 col1, class, class1, class2
 123, 2,5,7
 122, 5,7,9
 124, 7,9,15
 125, 9,15,2
 126, 15,2,19
 127, 2,19,5
 128, 19,5,7
 129, 5,7,9
 130, 7,9,3
 179, 9,3,NA,
 180, 3,NA,NA
```

This solves only if my number of fields in the patter is same, but mine will change. Some patterns could even 5 to 7 fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `shift` from `data.table`, then `paste` the elements together and check where we have `579`

```
n <- 3
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, which(do.call(paste0, shift(class, seq(n)-1, type = "lead"))=="579")]
#[1] 2 8
```

Or instead of `paste` we can use `Map` with `Reduce`

```
setDT(df1)[,  which(Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, shift(class, seq(n)-1, 
             type = "lead"), c(5, 7, 9))))]
#[1] 2 8
```

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat more lengthy base R alternative, in principle similar to @akrun's answer:

```
which(do.call(paste0, cbind(df1, with(df1, class[seq_along(class)+1]),
                             with(df1, class[seq_along(class)+2]))[-1]) == "579")
#[1] 2 8
```

**data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c(123L, 122L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 
                               129L, 130L, 179L, 180L), class = c(2L, 5L,
                               7L, 9L, 15L, 2L, 19L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 3L)),
                              .Names = c("col1", "class"), class = "data.frame", 
                               row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: I think there is also an option with `matrix`