# R - Identify a sequence of row elements by groups in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Consider the following sample dataframe:

```
> df
   id name time
1   1    b   10
2   1    b   12
3   1    a    0
4   2    a    5
5   2    b   11
6   2    a    9
7   2    b    7
8   1    a   15
9   2    b    1
10  1    a    3

df = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
    name = c("b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"
    ), time = c(10L, 12L, 0L, 5L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 15L, 1L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "time"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to identify and record all sequences `seq <- c("a","b")`, where "a" precedes "b" based on "time" column, for each id. No other names between "a" and "b" are permitted. Real sequence length is at least 5. 
The expected result for the sample data is

```
  a  b
1 3 10
2 5  7
3 9 11
```

There is a similar question [Finding rows in R dataframe where a column value follows a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770801/finding-rows-in-r-dataframe-where-a-column-value-follows-a-sequence). However, it is not clear to me how to deal with "id" column in my case. Is it a way to solve the problem using "dplyr"?

Comment: It's unclear how you arrive at your desired result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

# sort data frame by id and time
df %>% arrange(id, time) %>% group_by(id) %>% 

       # get logical vector indicating rows of a followed by b and mark each pair as unique
       # by cumsum
       mutate(ab = name == "a" & lead(name) == "b", g = cumsum(ab)) %>% 

       # subset rows where conditions are met
       filter(ab | lag(ab)) %>% 

       # reshape your data frame to wide format
       select(-ab) %>% spread(name, time)


#Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
#Groups: id [2]

#     id     g     a     b
#* <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     3    10
#2     2     1     5     7
#3     2     2     9    11
```

---

If length of the sequence is larger than two, then you will need to check multiple lags, and one option of this is to use `shift` function(which accepts a vector as lag/lead steps) from `data.table` combined with `Reduce`, say if we need to check pattern `abb`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(data.table)
pattern = c("a", "b", "b")
len_pattern = length(pattern)

df %>% arrange(id, time) %>% group_by(id) %>% 

       # same logic as before but use Reduce function to check multiple lags condition
       mutate(ab = Reduce("&", Map("==", shift(name, n = 0:(len_pattern - 1), type = "lead"), pattern)), 
              g = cumsum(ab)) %>% 

       # use reduce or to subset sequence rows having the same length as the pattern
       filter(Reduce("|", shift(ab, n = 0:(len_pattern - 1), type = "lag"))) %>% 

       # make unique names
       group_by(g, add = TRUE) %>% mutate(name = paste(name, 1:n(), sep = "_")) %>% 

       # pivoting the table to wide format
       select(-ab) %>% spread(name, time) 

#Source: local data frame [1 x 5]
#Groups: id, g [1]

#     id     g   a_1   b_2   b_3
#* <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     3    10    12
```

Comment: I was going to post this, but it's more or less the same thing: `df %>% arrange(id, time) %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(ifelse(name == 'b', lag(name) == 'a', lead(name) == 'b')) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(i = rep(seq(n()/2), each = 2)) %>% spread(name, time) %>% select(a, b)`

Comment: @alistaire I think you can still post it as an answer, it's a different approach as for how to create unique id for each pair.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for! It will be easy to extend for longer sequences such as "abaab" or "abccd". Can you suggest how to deal with sequences which length isn't known prior to executing? I.e. I don't know if sequence is "ab" or "aabbb"...

Comment: There is a problem with this approach when using similar "name" sequences. Suppose  > df = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),name=c("a","a","a","a","a","a"),time=c(0,2,4,1,3,5)) and we are looking for ("a","a"), the resulting dataframe is incorrect. Same with ("a","a","a")

Comment: In that case, you probably need to rethink what you need. for c("a", "a") instance. the result would be (0, 2) or (0, 2), (2, 4) for id == 1?

Comment: (0, 2), (2, 4) is preferable results; however, both answers are acceptable in my case. I've just explored extreme cases.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an `ifelse` in `filter` with `lag` and `lead`, and then `tidyr::spread` to reshape to wide:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% arrange(id, time) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
    filter(ifelse(name == 'b',    # if name is b...
                  lag(name) == 'a',    # is the previous name a?
                  lead(name) == 'b')) %>%    # else if name is not b, is next name b?
    ungroup() %>% mutate(i = rep(seq(n() / 2), each = 2)) %>%    # create indices to spread by
    spread(name, time) %>% select(a, b)    # spread to wide and clean up

## # A tibble: 3 × 2
##       a     b
## * <int> <int>
## 1     3    10
## 2     5     7
## 3     9    11
```

---

Based on the comment below, here's a version that uses `gregexpr` to find the first index of a matched pattern, which while more complicated, scales more easily to longer patterns like `"aabb"`:

```
df %>% group_by(pattern = 'aabb', id) %>%    # add pattern as column, group
    arrange(time) %>%
    # collapse each group to a string for name and a list column for time
    summarise(name = paste(name, collapse = ''), time = list(time)) %>% 
    # group and add list-column of start indices for each match
    rowwise() %>% mutate(i = gregexpr(pattern, name)) %>% 
    unnest(i, .drop = FALSE) %>%    # expand, keeping other list columns
    filter(i != -1) %>%    # chop out rows with no match from gregexpr
    rowwise() %>%    # regroup
    # subset with sequence from index through pattern length 
    mutate(time = list(time[i + 0:(nchar(pattern) - 1)]), 
           pattern = strsplit(pattern, '')) %>%    # expand pattern to list column
    rownames_to_column('match') %>%    # add rownames as match index column
    unnest(pattern, time) %>%    # expand matches in parallel
    # paste sequence onto each letter (important for spreading if repeated letters)
    group_by(match) %>% mutate(pattern = paste0(pattern, seq(n()))) %>% 
    spread(pattern, time)    # spread to wide form

## Source: local data frame [1 x 8]
## Groups: match [1]
## 
##   match    id  name     i    a1    a2    b3    b4
## * <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
## 1     1     1 aabba     1     0     3    10    12
```

Note that if the pattern doesn't happen to be in alphabetical order, the resulting columns will not be ordered by their indices. Since indices are preserved, though, you can sort with something like `select(1:4, parse_number(names(.)[-1:-4]) + 4)`.

Comment: Great solution! How it can be extended to use on longer sequences like "abaaaab"?

Comment: You could do multiple lags, but at that point it probably makes more sense to paste the groups together and use `gregexpr`.

Answer (score 6):

It's somewhat convoluted, but how about a rolling join?

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(df), id, time)

df[ name == "b" ][
    df[, if(name == "a") .(time = last(time)), by=.(id, name, r = rleid(id,name))],
    on = .(id, time),
    roll = -Inf,
    nomatch = 0,
    .(a = i.time, b = x.time)
]

   a  b
1: 3 10
2: 5  7
3: 9 11
```