# Replace cells when sequence of row elements identified in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, tidyverse

I currently have a dataset which can be simplified as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE), 
           c(0,3,0,5,5,0,0,0,7), c("a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d","a"))
colnames(df) <- c("ID", "Status", "Number", "Letter")

  ID Status Number Letter
1  1   TRUE      0      a
2  1  FALSE      3      b
3  1   TRUE      0      c
4  2  FALSE      5      d
5  2  FALSE      5      a
6  2   TRUE      0      b
7  3   TRUE      0      c
8  3   TRUE      0      d
9  3  FALSE      7      a
```

Basically, I want to identify the IDs for which TRUE occurs before FALSE. Then, I want to replace the Status and Number in the rows that show TRUE (i.e. rows 1,7,8) by the subsequent FALSE row (i.e. rows 2,9,9). The final result should look as follows:

```
  ID Status Number Letter
1  1  FALSE      3      a
2  1  FALSE      3      b
3  1   TRUE      0      c
4  2  FALSE      5      d
5  2  FALSE      5      a
6  2   TRUE      0      b
7  3  FALSE      7      c
8  3  FALSE      7      d
9  3  FALSE      7      a
```

The last column only indicates that I have other variables that are observation-specific and I cannot simply replace the entire row by the subsequent one.

So far, from this post ([R - Identify a sequence of row elements by groups in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130912/r-identify-a-sequence-of-row-elements-by-groups-in-a-dataframe)), I managed to obtain the first part:

```
library(tidyverse)
extract <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(ifelse(Status == FALSE,
                lag(Status) == TRUE,
                lead(Status) == FALSE)) 

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Status Number Letter
  <dbl> <lgl>   <dbl> <fct> 
1    1. TRUE       0. a     
2    1. FALSE      3. b     
3    3. TRUE       0. d     
4    3. FALSE      7. a
```

I would very much appreciate any help how to proceed from here. I tried to specify my question as precisely as possible, let me know if anything is unclear.

---

Edit: Following @Henrik's suggestion, I will add some more complexity to my question. This dataset should work in this regard:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4),c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,
                                                  FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE), 
                 c(0,0,0,5,5,0,0,0,7,0,6,0,3,0), c("a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d","a","b",
                                                   "c","d","a","b"))
colnames(df) <- c("ID", "Status", "Number", "Letter")

> df
   ID Status Number Letter
1   1   TRUE      0      a
2   1   TRUE      0      b
3   1   TRUE      0      c
4   2  FALSE      5      d
5   2  FALSE      5      a
6   2   TRUE      0      b
7   3   TRUE      0      c
8   3   TRUE      0      d
9   3  FALSE      7      a
10  4   TRUE      0      b
11  4  FALSE      6      c
12  4   TRUE      0      d
13  4  FALSE      3      a
14  4   TRUE      0      b
```

Here is my proposed solution which, however, does not work for individual rows (cf. 12):

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Status2 = if (!all(Status)) replace(Status, cumsum(!Status) < 1, FALSE) else TRUE,
         Number2 = if (!all(Status)) replace(Number, cumsum(!Status) < 1,
                                                      first(Number[Status == FALSE])) 
                   else first(replace(Number, cumsum(!Status) < 1, Number[Status == TRUE])))

> df2
# A tibble: 14 x 6
# Groups:   ID [4]
      ID Status Number Letter Status2 Number2
   <dbl> <lgl>   <dbl> <fct>  <lgl>     <dbl>
 1    1. TRUE       0. a      TRUE         0.
 2    1. TRUE       0. b      TRUE         0.
 3    1. TRUE       0. c      TRUE         0.
 4    2. FALSE      5. d      FALSE        5.
 5    2. FALSE      5. a      FALSE        5.
 6    2. TRUE       0. b      TRUE         0.
 7    3. TRUE       0. c      FALSE        7.
 8    3. TRUE       0. d      FALSE        7.
 9    3. FALSE      7. a      FALSE        7.
10    4. TRUE       0. b      FALSE        6.
11    4. FALSE      6. c      FALSE        6.
12    4. TRUE       0. d      TRUE         0.
13    4. FALSE      3. a      FALSE        3.
14    4. TRUE       0. b      TRUE         0.
```

The result for Number2 in row 12 should correspond to the subsequent row, i.e. be 3.

Comment: Can there be several runs of `FALSE`, so that 'Numbers' corresponding each run of `TRUE` should be filled by values from the next subsequent run of `FALSE`? E.g. for ID = 1, that there is a fourth row (or more) of `FALSE`.

Comment: Also, are original 'Numbers' for `TRUE` always `0` as in the example?

Comment: @Hendrik, it would be possible to have the order TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ... for the same ID. However, for each ID, the Number will be the same for all rows of TRUE and all rows of FALSE, so it should - in my opinion - not matter by which row of FALSE we replace it with. 

Regarding your second question: Yes, in my dataset, all rows whose status is TRUE will also be assigned the number 0.

Comment: "for each ID, the Number will be the same for [...] all rows of FALSE". I assume this is not the case given e.g. the `FALSE` Numbers in ID 4: 6 and 3. Please also add the desired result for row 12.

Comment: @Henrik, apologies. I am new to SO and still getting used to the specifics of this forum. You are right, in my original dataset, all rows (given the ID) have the same number. However, I added generality to it in ID = 4 since I may come across a similar scenario in the future where I would need this trick. Thank you for helping me to improve my post!

Comment: Well, it's nothing strange about the 'specifics'; people develop their answer based on the input, the logic you describe and the desired output you present. Unfortunately the logic is still unclear: you write: "I want to replace the Status and Number in the rows that show TRUE [...] by the _subsequent_ FALSE. However, in row 12 you want to replace the Number with the _previous_ `FALSE` Number (6 from row 11). On the other hand this last 'logic' is _not_ applied to the `TRUE` on row 6: here Status and Number are _not_ replaced by values on from the preceeding `FALSE` on row 5....;)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. To be honest, for row it does not matter whether it will be the previous or the subsequent line, but I changed it to be in line with my previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(flag = coalesce(Status == TRUE &
                           lead(Status == FALSE), FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(ID, grp = cumsum(+(Status != lag(Status, default = "rndom")))) %>%
  mutate(Status = ifelse(any(flag == TRUE), FALSE, Status)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(-flag, -grp)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
     ID Status Number Letter
  <dbl> <lgl>   <dbl> <fct> 
1     1 FALSE       0 a     
2     1 FALSE       3 b     
3     1 TRUE        0 c     
4     2 FALSE       5 d     
5     2 FALSE       5 a     
6     2 TRUE        0 b     
7     3 FALSE       0 c     
8     3 FALSE       0 d     
9     3 FALSE       7 a
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I am trying to run your solution, I get the following error message: "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=integer]." I am fairly new to R and not familiar with coalesce or the syntax of your solution - any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not really sure what could this be about. I've run it again on your example and it works. What is your `dplyr` version? Perhaps update to the latest one and try again.

Comment: thank you. That was indeed the issue I had. Could I ask you one more question? I have tried to replicate your solution for the Numbers column as well such that it displays the result from the subsequent row adding this line to mutate: Number2 = ifelse(any(flag == TRUE), lead(Number[Status == FALSE]), Number. However, this unfortunately coerces NAs. Do you happen to have an idea how to fix this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: For this it would the best if you edit your question with the desired output - as I'm not 100% what it would look like.

Comment: In Edit #2, I show my desired output and tried to state the question more clearly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Another option where we `replace` all values for which `cumsum(!Status) < 1` is `TRUE` with `FALSE`, i.e. is all values before the first `FALSE` will be replaced.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(new_status = replace(Status, cumsum(!Status) < 1, FALSE))
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID Status Number Letter new_status
#  <dbl> <lgl>   <dbl> <fct>  <lgl>     
#1     1 TRUE        0 a      FALSE     
#2     1 FALSE       3 b      FALSE     
#3     1 TRUE        0 c      TRUE      
#4     2 FALSE       5 d      FALSE     
#5     2 FALSE       5 a      FALSE     
#6     2 TRUE        0 b      TRUE      
#7     3 TRUE        0 c      FALSE     
#8     3 TRUE        0 d      FALSE     
#9     3 FALSE       7 a      FALSE
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I just edited your answer for completeness (regarding the adjustment of numbers which I was able to do myself based on your solution).

Comment: On second thought, this does not work for me as soon as I have an ID for which status is always true (i.e. ID = 4, Status = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)).

Would this be an option instead?

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(realStatus = !all(Status), new_status = if(!all(Status)) replace(Status, cumsum(!Status) < 1, FALSE) else TRUE)

Comment: @WillyWonka In order to help people help, please edit your question to include an example of _sufficient complexity_. Also add the info in [your comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807061/replace-cells-when-sequence-of-row-elements-identified-in-data-frame#comment96430341_54807061) to the question. Cheers