# R - Find a sequence of row elements based on time constraints in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Consider the following dataframe (ordered by id and time):

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,7),rep(2,5)), event = c("a","b","b","b","a","b","a","a","a","b","a","a"), time = c(1,3,6,12,24,30,32,1,2,6,17,24))
df
   id event time
1   1     a    1
2   1     b    3
3   1     b    6
4   1     b   12
5   1     a   24
6   1     b   30
7   1     a   42
8   2     a    1
9   2     a    2
10  2     b    6
11  2     a   17
12  2     a   24
```

I want to count how many times a given sequence of events appears in each "id" group. Consider the following sequence with time constraints:

```
seq <- c("a", "b", "a")
time_LB <- c(0, 2, 12)
time_UB <- c(Inf, 8, 18)
```

It means that event "a" can start at any time, event "b" must start no earlier than 2 and no later than 8 after event "a", another event "a" must start no earlier than 12 and no later than 18 after event "b".
Some rules for creating sequences:

1. Events don't need to be consecutive with respect to "time" column. For example, `seq` can be constructed from rows 1, 3, and 5.
2. To be counted, sequences must have different first event. For example, if `seq` = rows 8, 10, and 11 was counted, then `seq` = rows 8, 10, and 12 must not be counted.
3. The events may be included in many constructed sequences if they do not violate the second rule. For example, we count both sequences: rows 1, 3, 5 and rows 5, 6, 7.

The expected result:

```
df1
  id count
1  1     2
2  2     2
```

There are some related questions in [R - Identify a sequence of row elements by groups in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130912/r-identify-a-sequence-of-row-elements-by-groups-in-a-dataframe/41131260#41131260) and [Finding rows in R dataframe where a column value follows a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770801/finding-rows-in-r-dataframe-where-a-column-value-follows-a-sequence).

Is it a way to solve the problem using "dplyr"?

Comment: slightly confused - take `id == 2`; Here `a=1,b=6,a=17` is the only case that satisfies the conditions right? so count should be 1 right? did i get the question right?

Comment: another seq is a=2,b=6,a=17 or  a=2,b=6,a=24

Comment: then we can also have `a=24, b=6, a=17`?

Comment: Did you mean a=2 not 24? If yes, rule 2 states that we can count only one of them

Comment: I'm still confused. No i meant 24 itself; since `a` can have any value between 0 and Inf? are we trying to search for all permutations?

Comment: So are you also interested in all instances of a seq ? Like, I haven't checked for it, but it occurs to me you might have seq 's that overlap or seq 's that occur within other seq 's (though idk if you do in your example, it may exist in your data). So are you interested in finding ALL seq 's or only mutually excusive seq 's? Must one seq end before another begins?

Comment: If "a" started at 24, b=6 cannot start after "a" as explained under time constraints

Comment: Yes, I am looking for all sequences with limitations on Rule 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for. It gives you the desired output. Note that there is a typo in your original question where you have a 32 instead of a 42 when you define the `time` column in `df`. I say this is a typo because it doesn't match your output immediately below the definition of `df`. I changed the 32 to a 42 in the code below.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,7),rep(2,5)), event = c("a","b","b","b","a","b","a","a","a","b","a","a"), time = c(1,3,6,12,24,30,42,1,2,6,17,24))

seq <- c("a", "b", "a")
time_LB <- c(0, 2, 12)
time_UB <- c(Inf, 8, 18)

df %>% 
  full_join(df,by='id',suffix=c('1','2')) %>% 
  full_join(df,by='id') %>% 
  rename(event3 = event, time3 = time) %>%
  filter(event1 == seq[1] & event2 == seq[2] & event3 == seq[3]) %>% 
  filter(time1 %>% between(time_LB[1],time_UB[1])) %>% 
  filter((time2-time1) %>% between(time_LB[2],time_UB[2])) %>% 
  filter((time3-time2) %>% between(time_LB[3],time_UB[3])) %>%
  group_by(id,time1) %>%
  slice(1) %>%   # slice 1 row for each unique id and time1 (so no duplicate time1s)
  group_by(id) %>% 
  count()
```

Here's the output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     2
```

Also, if you omit the last 2 parts of the dplyr pipe that do the counting (to see the sequences it is matching), you get the following sequences:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 7]
Groups: id, time1 [4]

     id event1 time1 event2 time2 event3 time3
  <dbl> <fctr> <dbl> <fctr> <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
1     1      a     1      b     6      a    24
2     1      a    24      b    30      a    42
3     2      a     1      b     6      a    24
4     2      a     2      b     6      a    24
```

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT REGARDING GENERALIZING THIS:** Yes it is possible to generalize this to arbitrary length sequences but requires some R voodoo. Most notably, note the use of `Reduce`, which allows you to apply a common function on a list of objects as well as `foreach`, which I'm borrowing from the `foreach` package to do some arbitrary looping. Here's the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(foreach)

df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,7),rep(2,5)), event = c("a","b","b","b","a","b","a","a","a","b","a","a"), time = c(1,3,6,12,24,30,42,1,2,6,17,24))

seq <- c("a", "b", "a")
time_LB <- c(0, 2, 12)
time_UB <- c(Inf, 8, 18)

multi_full_join = function(df1,df2) {full_join(df1,df2,by='id')}
df_list = foreach(i=1:length(seq)) %do% {df} 
df2 = Reduce(multi_full_join,df_list)

names(df2)[grep('event',names(df2))] = paste0('event',seq_along(seq))
names(df2)[grep('time',names(df2))] = paste0('time',seq_along(seq))
df2 = df2 %>% mutate_if(is.factor,as.character)

df2 = df2 %>% 
  mutate(seq_string = Reduce(paste0,df2 %>% select(grep('event',names(df2))) %>% as.list)) %>% 
  filter(seq_string == paste0(seq,collapse=''))

time_diff = df2 %>% select(grep('time',names(df2))) %>%
  t %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  lapply(diff) %>% 
  unlist %>%  matrix(ncol=2,byrow=TRUE) %>% 
  as.data.frame

foreach(i=seq_along(time_diff),.combine=data.frame) %do%
{
  time_diff[[i]] %>% between(time_LB[i+1],time_UB[i+1])
} %>% 
  Reduce(`&`,.) %>% 
  which %>% 
  slice(df2,.) %>% 
  filter(time1 %>% between(time_LB[1],time_UB[1])) %>% # deal with time1 bounds, which we skipped over earlier
  group_by(id,time1) %>%
  slice(1) # slice 1 row for each unique id and time1 (so no duplicate time1s)
```

This outputs the following:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 8]
Groups: id, time1 [4]

     id event1 time1 event2 time2 event3 time3 seq_string
  <dbl>  <chr> <dbl>  <chr> <dbl>  <chr> <dbl>      <chr>
1     1      a     1      b     6      a    24        aba
2     1      a    24      b    30      a    42        aba
3     2      a     1      b     6      a    24        aba
4     2      a     2      b     6      a    24        aba
```

If you want just the counts, you can `group_by(id)` then `count()` as in the original code snippet.

Comment: Yes, it is a typo... must be 42. Thanks for fixing it. Can your code be modified to work with sequence of any length? Actual sequences have from 2 to 10 events.

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer above to include a generalized version.

Comment: @dmitriy873 Please let me know if this does not work as expected or if I should add any further clarification to the code itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's easier to represent event sequences as strings and use regex:

```
df.str = lapply(split(df, df$id), function(d) {
    z = rep('-', tail(d,1)$time); z[d$time] = as.character(d$event); z })

df.str = lapply(df.str, paste, collapse='')

# > df.str
# $`1`
# [1] "a-b--b-----b-----------a-----b-----------a"
#
# $`2`
# [1] "aa---b----------a------a"


df1 = lapply(df.str, function(s) length(gregexpr('(?=a.{1,7}b.{11,17}a)', s, perl=T)[[1]]))

> data.frame(id=names(df1), count=unlist(df1))
#   id count
# 1  1     2
# 2  2     2
```

Comment: This is a very nice idea! However, real event may have millions seconds between them. Will it increase execution time?

Comment: @ dmitriy873 Like, I get that both answers here work, but I really don't like either of them, because they seem more like work around rather than directly confronting the issue. What we're talking about here in a sense is signal detection. So sure these work on a contrived example but what about when the sequence is super complex, or the environment you are searching in is very noisy (lots of false possitives to omit)? These answers won't scale well.

Comment: Care to share a better solution?